# How to Find and Update Array of Objects in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, object, powershell-4.0, updating

Am trying to track which Windows file shares are not being used in our organization. I can get a list of all the shares and of all the shares currently being accessed. My plan is to get the list of shares currently being accessed and increment the use count for each of shares. At the end of the time period shares whose use count is still 0 are the ones we could look at retiring.

Have the PowerShell to create the base file of shares with each one having a use count of 0. Also have the PowerShell to get the list of shares currently being used. Trying to put the base file list into an array of objects and then search the array for each sharename in the active array and if it is found increment the use count. Am unable to reference the objects in the base array.

```
$shares = "ShareName", "UseCount"
$shares = @()
$shares = Get-Content -Path "c:\base_shares.lis"
foreach ($object in $shares) {
    Write-Host "Sharename is:" $object.ShareName
}
```

`$shares` looks like:

```
ShareName UseCount
--------- --------
shareA           0
shareB           0
shareC           0
```

Output from the script is:

```
Sharename is:
Sharename is:
Sharename is:
Sharename is:
Sharename is:
```

I expect the output to return shareA, shareB and shareC.

Comment: You wrote formatted PowerShell output to a text file. When you read that text file back into a variable your data is plain strings, not the original objects you had when creating the output. The strings don't have a property `ShareName`. Use `Export-Csv` for creating `base_shares.lis`, and use `Import-Csv` for importing it in your script.

Comment: Thank-you Ansgar!  Now on to searching for matching share names and updating the corresponding use count.